# How to integrate Fake.Build and JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider, f#-fake

In our team, we're (happily) using JetBrains Rider as IDE for our C# and frontend projects. Now, we've inherited a project that uses Fake.Build as a build system. It works very well on console, but I didn't find a good way to integrate it into the Run/Debug Dialogs Rider offers. Some of our devs clearly prefer the Gui to control their builds, and I want to offer them a good develop experience.

How can I integrate Rider with Fake.Build so we can enjoy the same comfort as we have with MSBuild-based builds?

Comment: Is your fake script only running build?
Normally it would do many more things, i.e. clean output folders, update assembly props, build, package, nuget, etc. If so, do you really want to run this all as part of usual `msbuild` or `dotnet build`?

Comment: Well, it allows to locally start three instances with 1 command (and hopefully soon 1 click in Rider?)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found until now is to integrate it is to create a package.json file and define script tasks that run the fake tasks:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "dotnet fake build -t run",
    "build": "dotnet fake build -t build",
    "test": "dotnet fake build -t test"
}
```

These can be clicked explicitly or easily added as config for run/debug in Rider.